# Read currently selected line

Tags: vba, ms-word

(this should propably be simple, but somehow i cannot find a solution.)

I simply want to read the current line of my selection into a variable in vba. I do not know the current paragraph. The selection is at the very beginning of the line.

My document looks like this.

[image: My Word doc]

First of all I select the first row of the table. Then i move one paragraph up. Now thats the line I want. As you can see in my second img, I only have the first character.

```
For Each tbl In fileInsertRange.Tables
    tbl.Rows(1).Select
    ' save caption
    Selection.Collapse
    Selection.MoveUp WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1

    tableCaption = Selection.Text
```

[image: Debugging]

Comment: Your edit changes a lot the content of your previous question, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store all your tables captions in a variable than try this code. Keep in mind you'd need to use the `tableCaption` variable right away before it gets overwritten by the next tables caption or add an array to store all of the captions.

```
Sub get_table_caption()

Dim currentTable As Table
Dim tableCaption As String

'Loop through all tables on active document
For Each currentTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

    'Get tables caption and store in a variable called "tableCaption"
    currentTable.Select
    Selection.Collapse
    Selection.MoveUp WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1
    Selection.Expand wdLine
    tableCaption = Selection.Text
    Debug.Print tableCaption

    'Do stuff with the tables caption

Next
End Sub
```

If you want to continue doing it your way by selecting the first row of the table and finding that tables caption than try this code:

```
Sub get_table_caption()

Dim tableCaption As String

    'Get tables caption and store in a variable called "tableCaption"
    Selection.Collapse
    Selection.MoveUp WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1
    Selection.Expand wdLine
    tableCaption = Selection.Text
    Debug.Print tableCaption

End Sub
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: `Selection.Expand wdLine` thats what I needed. Thanks.